# cannot display the slider of a scrollviewer

Tags: wpf

I can't get the slider for a scrollviewer to display.  I have a listbox in a wrappanel.  The listbox has a list of numbers.  The list can be long enough to extend off of the bottom of the screen, so a scrollviewer is needed, but no matter how I set scrollviewer properties, or even if I put the listbox inside a scrollviewer inside the wrappanel, the slider doesn't appear.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's the XAML:

```
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
       <ListBox x:Name="lstBxCollisions" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Height="auto" Width="auto" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding MainWindow.lstBxCollisions}"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Document="{Binding SingleAccidentFlowDocument}">
        </FlowDocumentReader>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your ListBox is inside WrapPanel, all its sizes are selected automatically and it begins to expand as the content size increases.
If you want it to appear ScrollBar, you need to fix the size of the ListBox by setting the actual height and width.
For example:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox x:Name="lstBxCollisions" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Height="100" Width="100" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding MainWindow.lstBxCollisions}"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    <FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Document="{Binding SingleAccidentFlowDocument}">
    </FlowDocumentReader>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I set the height of the ListBox to 400 and the Scrollbar worked just fine.  Now I have a new problem.  A ghost scrollbar appeared to the right of the real scrollbar.

Comment: @Jerry, Apparently this is related to any container that has ScrollViewer outside the code that you showed.
In the code presented by you, the Grid.Row = "5" and Grid.Column = "1" properties are meaningless, because the FlowDocumentReader object is not inside the Grid.
If you provide a whole code, I can help you with the layout.